# Zod - Property 'infer' does not exist on type 'typeof import(.../node_modules/zod/lib/external)

Tags: javascript, typescript, zod

I got the Typescript error:

`Property 'infer' does not exist on type 'typeof import(.../node_modules/zod/lib/external)`

on the code:
`const CampaignForm = z.infer<typeof CampaignSchema>;`

Looking at the docs and node_modules the property is there.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The issue was using `const` instead of `type`.

**Expected**: `type CampaignForm = z.infer<typeof CampaignSchema>;`

**Actual**: `const CampaignForm = z.infer<typeof CampaignSchema>;`

The error is misleading.

Comment: Absolutely this was the case.

Comment: Saved me some frustration there Itay. Thank you.